# adding clocking support to heroku with python django

Tags: python, django, heroku, cron

This [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python) teaches how to run background jobs in heroku.

I have my `clock.py` file, in the same directory where `Procfile` is.

Following is my clock.py file:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from subscription.views import send_subs_mail
sched = Scheduler()


@sched.cron_schedule(day_of_week='sat', hour=23)
def scheduled_job():
    print 'This job is run every saturday at 11pm.'
    send_subs_mail()

sched.start()

while True:
    pass
```

I have updated my Procfile, to look as follows:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3 
clock: python clock.py
```

Earlier it used to look like:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3
```

Having done all this, I do the following in my terminal:

```
heroku ps:scale clock=1
```

And I get the following error:

> Scaling clock processes... failed  !    No such type as clock.

I have updated my requirements file, as mentioned in the article.

and here is the `heroku logs`

```
2013-05-22T15:52:08.200587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:48070 -w 3 clock: python clock.py`
2013-05-22T15:52:09.081883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2013-05-22T15:52:10.691985+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
2013-05-22T15:52:10.683457+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE
2013-05-22T15:52:10.691843+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-22T15:52:12.504514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2013-05-22T15:52:12.525765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-05-22T15:52:12.525765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-05-22T15:52:16.198417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:55149 -w 3 clock: python clock.py`
2013-05-22T15:52:17.343513+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE
2013-05-22T15:52:17.343513+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
2013-05-22T15:52:17.343513+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-22T15:52:18.557818+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-05-22T15:52:18.542409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Each process type should be on it's own line, like so:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 3
clock: python clock.py
```

Hope that helps!